# How to prevent firing of event multiple times on rapid click of a button in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, command

How can I avoid invoking of the same event multiple times when a button is clicked rapidly.

Below is the code:
I've created a Custom Delegate Command as below

- View Model

```
namespace TestProject.ViewModels
{
    public class TestViewModel 
    {

        public CustomDelegateCommand MenuButtonClickCommand { get; set; }


        public TestViewModel()
        {
          MenuButtonClickCommand = new CustomDelegateCommand (async () => await ShowMenuAction());
        }

        
        private async Task ShowMenuAction()
        {
            //await some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

- CustomDelegateCommand.cs

```
public class CustomDelegateTimerCommand : DelegateCommand
{
        public CustomDelegateTimerCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> validateMethod, Action onBusy = default(Action)) : base(executeMethod)
        {
            BackgroundTaskWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
            _validateMethod = validateMethod;
            _onBusy = onBusy;
        }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is whenever a user clicks on the button rapidly, the menu list popup is opening multiple times.
I have lot of commands in my project and I need a solution that would work globally.

I tried to resolve the issue like below using ObservesCanExecute() but I don't like the idea of creating a separate variable for every command as I've a lot of commands in my project and I don't want the button to go in to disabled state when CanExecute = false.

- ViewModel

```
MenuButtonClickCommand = new CustomDelegateCommand (async () => await ShowMenuAction().ObservesCanExecute(() => CanExecute );

private async Task ShowMenuAction()
        {
            CanExecute = false;

            //await some stuff

            CanExecute = true;
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could bind the  `IsEnabled` of the button and set it to false when user click it and set it to true after handling logic .

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions to it. One is when you use, MVVM other is when you dont.
The non MVVM solution is delaying the execution of method for certain amount of time, like this:

```
    public class SingleClickListener
{
    private bool hasClicked;
    private Action<object, EventArgs> _setOnClick;
    public SingleClickListener(Action<object, EventArgs> setOnClick)
    {
        _setOnClick = setOnClick;
    }
    public void OnClick(object v, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!hasClicked)
        {
            _setOnClick(v, e);
            hasClicked = true;
        }
        reset();
    }
    private void reset()
    {
        Android.OS.Handler mHandler = new Android.OS.Handler();
        mHandler.PostDelayed(new Action(() => { hasClicked = false; }), 500);
    }

}
```

And then when you subscribe the onclick event:

```
                var buttonNa = new Button { Text = "Test Button" };
            buttonNa.Clicked += new SingleClickListener((sender, e) =>
            {

                //DO something
            }).OnClick;
```

The Mvvm solution is bit more complicated, but its not as hacky.

```
            TestCommand = new Command(
            execute: async () =>
            {
                IsEditing = true;
                RefreshCanExecutes();
                //Fire Method
         TestMethod();
            },
            canExecute: () =>
            {
                return !IsEditing;
            });

        public void RefreshCanExecutes()
    {
        (TestCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();
    }
        public void TestMethod()
    {
        //DO something
        IsEditing = false;
        RefreshCanExecutes();
    }
```

Obviously dont forget to bind your commands to xaml :)
also second solution actually disables the button, so user cannot even tap it, first one however only ignores further taps, till time delay has finished.

Comment: Thanks, Both of the above mentioned solutions would work but since I have lot of commands in my project I want to avoid creating a separate variable for each command(IsEditing).

Comment: I'm affraid you wont be able to. Unless you use global Variable declared somewhere in App.xaml.cs, but that would disable all the buttons once you tap one.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new class which inherits from `Xamarin.Forms.Button` with delay in click event, than add it to your xmal.

```
public class DelayedButton : Xamarin.Forms.Button
{
    public DelayedButton()
    {
        this.Clicked += DelayedButton_Clicked;
    }

    async private void DelayedButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsEnabled = false;
        await Task.Delay(Delay);
        this.IsEnabled = true;
    }


    public int Delay { get; set; } = 500;
}
```

In XAML：

```
<yourNameSpace:DelayedButton Delay="300" Text="DelayedButton" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
```